# Port was prevented from using MAC address because it is pinned to port

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I am getting the error "Port {GUID} was prevented from using MAC address xxx because it is pinned to port {GUID}" Source VMSMP, event ID 28 in the event log.   And frequent network slowdowns. This is in a simple HyperV 2008 Server R2 environment with three guest OSs.    The event log is showing these happening multiple times per day and sometimes within minutes of each other.

As per some suggestions I have assigned static MAC addresses to each of the three guest OSs. I have recreated the virtual switch.   Some of the items in the event log mention SWITCHPORT but I think those were from before I recreated the virtual switch.

There are two NICs in the server.

The first of these events started 2014-09-29 but they only happened every few days back then.   I'm suspecting some kind of patch in 2014-09.

Added later:  There is only the one virtual switch.  There are two RealTek PCIe GBE Family Controller NICs according to Device Manager.  Not sure of the exact model.    There are no other HyperV servers on the LAN.

Added later:   The server is part of a small network.  It's possible that the warnings started when I installed two TP-Link AC1750 Archer C7 dual band wireless access points in bridging mode.   However there is a GB switch between the server and the one WAP.   And I wouldn't think a wonky switch or WAP would cause this kind of problem.

Comment: Please add some more details about the network setup - how many virtual switches, how many physical, the configuration of both.  Model of NICs.  Any other hyperv hosts on the same LAN?

Comment: Some details added.